# Missing required parameters for [Route: tender_detail] Locale Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Got an error after adding localization to my laravel project.
Here is my web.php

```
//Tender
Route::group(['prefix' => '{language}/tender', 'middleware' => ['permission:tender-page']], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'TenderController@index')->name('tender');
    Route::get('/add', 'TenderController@add')->name('tender_add');
    Route::get('/{id}', 'TenderController@detail')->name('tender_detail');
});
```

Here is my error

```
ErrorException thrown with message:
"Missing required parameters for [Route: tender_detail] [URI: {language}/tender/{id}]. 
(View: /Users/admin/Desktop/dev/medicare/resources/views/layouts/template.blade.php) 
(View: /Users/admin/Desktop/dev/medicare/resources/views/layouts/template.blade.php)"
```

Here is part of my template.blade.php

```
<li class="{{ Request::is('tender*') ? 'active' : '' }}">
<a href="{{ route('tender', ['language' => app()->getLocale()]) }}">
<i class="notika-icon notika-house"></i> {{ __('tender') }} </a>
</li>
```

Here is route to the tender_detail page

```
<a href="{{ route('tender_detail', ['language' => app()->getLocale(), 'id' => 1])}}">ЛОТ 123456-ОК3</a>
```

Comment: You're calling the `tender_detail` route somewhere in your code, but you're not passing the `id` parameter. In the template example you provided above, I only see `tender` route. Find where did you call `tender_detail` and provide that part of the code as well.

Comment: @zlatan Thanks for your answer, i provide link to tender_detail page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in my language changer links.
`

```
<li class="nav-item">
   <a href="{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(), 'ru') }}" class="nav-link">RU</a>
 </li>
 <li class="nav-item">
   <a href="{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(), 'tr') }}" class="nav-link">TR</a>
 </li>
```

`

when i delete this links, routes start work

Answer (score 0):

Try changing from

```
<a href="{{ route('tender', ['language' => app()->getLocale()]) }}">
```

to something like

```
<a href="{{ route('tender', ['language' => app()->getLocale(), 'id' => 'your-tender-id']) }}">
```

provide your `tender-id` in the route method

Comment: I send '$id' parameter to 'tender_detail' page. I update my question, i provide tender-id and it didnt work.

Comment: It worked without 'language' prefix. After i add 'language' prefix it broke

Comment: True that is the case the error is coming from this line 'Route::group(['prefix' => '{language}/tender', 'middleware' => ['permission:tender-page']], function() {..' .You see the language parameter is required yet you cant pass it through the route method because it is not part or the route params. Ive tried to fix that and it seems tricky. can I try a different approach where you dont pass a paramemter to the prefix? Let me check this out first

Comment: This is 
`<a href="{{ route('tender', ['language' => app()->getLocale()]) }}">` 
the link to the `Route::get('/', 'TenderController@index')->name('tender');`
But `tender_detail ` page require `$id` parameter and also `language`

Comment: The thing that we are doing is basically instead of passing the `language` parameter through the prefix were passing it through individual links sothat the param can be passed via the `route()` method. Your previous implementation has a route which can only access `id` param yet its under a group that needs the `language` param that cant be passed through the `route` method thats why you did get the error in the first place

Comment: Yes, it is. But other routes are working. This 
`Route::get('/', 'TenderController@index')->name('tender');
 Route::get('/add', 'TenderController@add')->name('tender_add');`
two work fine. I send `language` parameter on both of this routes. But when i try to send both  `language` with `id` occur error

Answer (score 0):

This edit will change change your urls alittle but i think it will work
Edit

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{language}/tender', 'middleware' => ['permission:tender-page']], function() {
        Route::get('/', 'TenderController@index')->name('tender');
        Route::get('/add', 'TenderController@add')->name('tender_add');
        Route::get('/{id}', 'TenderController@detail')->name('tender_detail');
    });
```

To this

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'tender', 'middleware' => ['permission:tender-page']], function() {
        Route::get('/{language}/', 'TenderController@index')->name('tender');
        Route::get('/{language}/add', 'TenderController@add')->name('tender_add');
        Route::get('/{language}/{id}', 'TenderController@detail')->name('tender_detail');
    });
```

then try something like this

```
<a href="{{ route('tender_detail', ['language' => app()->getLocale(), 'id' => 1])}}">ЛОТ 123456-ОК3</a>
```